# PrimeNG p-table & progressBar issue

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG's components p-Table and p-progressBar to develop a tool.
But I found when I scroll the table, the progress bar can't be hidden.
Please take a look at the capture below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuTiB.png)

Component A using p-table as the calendar:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KnPL.png)
Here is the source of app-task-progres:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRldL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8yFF.png)

See if someone can save me from the trouble. Thanks!

Comment: Pleaser take a while to replace all occurrences of "enter image description here" with relevant description